# How to use 'git pull' from the command line?

Tags: git, command-line, ssh, github, nant

We were using a build script to automate our publishing process and it was working with SVN but now we are using Git and need to do some command line operations to pull from our remote repository.

I was able to follow the guide [here](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) and using the Git bash it works great. However, I need to perform these tasks from the Windows command line so that they can be executed by the script.

`git pull origin master` works in the Git bash.

```
cd "c:\program files (x86)\git\bin
git --git-dir=path\to\.git pull origin master
```

fails with an error

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Obviously my SSH key is not being used properly or something. I'm so new to this that I really have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the HOME environment variable in Windows to your home folder (`c:\users\username`).

( you can confirm that this is the problem by doing `echo $HOME` in git bash and `echo %HOME%` in cmd - latter might not be available )

Comment: Do you know where I should "set the HOME environment variable"?

Comment: Adding a system variable called "HOME" with a value of "%USERPROFILE%" worked. Thank you.

Comment: Mind the case-sensitiveness. It should be `$HOME` and not `$home`

Answer (score 1):

Open up your git bash and type

```
echo $HOME
```

This shall be the same folder as you get when you open your command window (cmd) and type

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

And – of course – the `.ssh` folder shall be present on THAT directory.

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to add the path of the privatekey file like this in terminal:

**ssh-add  "path to the privatekeyfile"**

and then execute the pull command